Shared X-axis spike remove tick marks from other subplots in Plotly?
When I attempt to create a shared hover spike across multiple subplots, I immediately lose the xticks on those subplots.
Is there any way I can fix this? I want to see the xtick labels on ALL of my subplots.
Reproducible Code
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    vertical_spacing=0.10)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0, 1, 2], y=[10, 11, 12]),
              row=3, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[100, 110, 120]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[3, 4, 5], y=[1000, 1100, 1200]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600,
                  title_text="Stacked Subplots with Shared X-Axes")

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_showticklabels=True,
    xaxis2_showticklabels=True,
    xaxis3_showticklabels=True,
)

# Uncomment these lines to draw the shared hover spike
# fig.update_traces(xaxis='x')
# fig.update_xaxes(spikemode='across+marker')

fig.show()

Before and After Chart

